# Unable to load modules that are installed in virtual environment

Tags: python, virtualenv

I am unable to import modules to my python files after installing them within a virtual environment. I get an error saying "No module named ___". Everything works fine outside of this particular environment and I have also had no problems within other virtual environments.

I created this virtual environment using "virtualenv venv". I activated the environment and installed a few modules using pip. The modules show up in the site-packages directory within the venv folder. "pip freeze" also lists all of the modules that I installed within the virtual environment. I am able to import and use modules that are in the "Lib" directory such as "os.py", but I am unable to import any of the modules within the sub directory "site-packages".

What am I doing wrong? How can I import these modules?

I am using Visual Studio Code and in the virtual environment I am using Python 3.7.3

Thank you in advance!

Comment: may be you should post a few screenshots for better understanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone else has this problem, I never could figure out what was wrong or how to fix it. I was able to get it working by just creating a new directory and re-creating the entire environment.